# Is it possible to order records based on MMM yyyy from Jan to Dec?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I am counting requests and grouping records on date. I am able to successfully achieve my result but I am unable to order records.

```
SELECT Count([RequestId]) as 'No. of Requests',
Format(convert(datetime,CAST([Timestamp] as datetime),120),'MMM yyyy') as 'Stamp Date'
FROM [Requests]
group by
Format(convert(datetime,CAST([Timestamp] as datetime),120),'MMM yyyy')
```

I need data in following structure:

No. of Requests = 12
Stamp Date = Aug 2019

but should be order by Jan to December.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a sortable data format such as yyyy-mm?

In any case, you can order by the minimum timestamp:

```
order by min([TimeStamp])
```

You might need to cast this as a `datetime`.  It is not clear what your original data looks like.